# Multivariable inequality quick question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value

So I want to graph: $$|z+1+i|<|z-2|$$

$z$ is a complex number.

After my calculation(with $z=x+iy$) I got: $$y<1-2x$$

When I put it in wolfram alpha the line is 1.5 on y axis and 0.8 on x axis. But the graph of function 1-2x is different. Why can’t I just graph the function and say that everything bellow it satisfies the inequality. What should I do to get the wolfram alpha graph or in other words the correct graph?

Comment: Your solution is not correct. For example, consider $z = 5 - 10i$. Your inequality accepts it but it does not satisfy the original inequation.

Comment: It should be $y \lt 1-3x$ and not $y \lt 1-2x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not correct. In fact\begin{align}\require{cancel}\lvert x+yi+1+i\rvert<\lvert x+yi-2\rvert&\iff(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2<(x-2)^2+y^2\\&\iff\cancel{x^2}+2x+1+\cancel{y^2}+2y+1<\cancel{x^2}-4x+4+\cancel{y^2}\\&\iff6x+2y-2<0\\&\iff3x+y<1\\&\iff y<1-3x.\end{align}

Comment: But still, if we graph 1-3x the y intercept is one, while if I put y<1-3x in wolfram alpha the y intercept is 1.5 Why is that so?

Comment: I don't know what is the exact question that you have asked WolframAlpha (you could provide a link), but I am sure that my answer is correct.

Comment: The link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3C1-3x

Comment: I am asking because this is different: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-3x

Comment: I don't understand how WolphramAlpha got that diagram.